# PHP5 SOAP Request - Associative array parameter dont send

Tags: php, soap-client

i write this script on php for do a SOAP request:

```
<?php
try {  
    $soapCli = new SoapClient('somewsdl', array('trace' => 1)); 
    print_r(
        $soapCli->__soapCall(
            "getUserByCf", array("xxx" => 'ok', "cf" => 'notok')
        )
    );
    echo "REQUEST HEAD:\n" . $soapCli->__getLastRequestHeaders() . "\n";
    echo "REQUEST:\n"      . $soapCli->__getLastRequest()        . "\n";
    unset($soapCli);
} catch (SoapFault $e) {  
    print_r($e);  
} 
?>
```

But on my wsdl first parameter are cf (and not xxx). So, server respost XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:ns1="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                   xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
                   SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getUserByCf>
      <cf xsi:type="xsd:string">ok</cf>
      <xxx xsi:type="xsd:string">notok</xxx>
    </ns1:getUserByCf>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

2 parameter are switched.

Why, if parameter on [`_soapCall()`](http://php.net/SoapClient._soapCall) are

> *"An array of the arguments to pass to the function. This can be either an ordered or an associative array."*

And I do an associative array, the request are not not associative?

Why soapCall not associate 2 parameter but Switch and associate 1° parameter at 1° name on WSDL and 2° at 2°?

Comment: AFAIK (untested here, but is stands to reason), the associative array (named paramaters) is only used in `non-WSDL` mode, in `WSDL` mode (which you are), the name will be replaced with the name already known for that position. So: wether you are using a ordered or associative array, the order of you arguments will be maintained, and only in `non-WSDL` mode will the key of the associative array be used. I'd go for the easier & more intuitive `$soapCli->getUserByCf('cfvalue','xxxvalue');` here too, makes it more clear a specific location matters.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an associative array for the parameters. That means you are using named parameters. Named parameters don't have any order, they have a name. The order is not important.

If you want to use unnamed parameters, you can do this by not using an associative array but just using numerical indexes, zero-based:

```
    $soapCli->__soapCall(
        "getUserByCf", array('ok', 'notok')
    )
```

Please take note that this most often does not work because many services require named parameters.